# What do you do in IIS if you get an error when trying to start your default web site and it says that it cannot be started because another web site may be using the same port?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

What do you do in IIS if you get an error when trying to start your default web site and it says that it cannot be started because another web site may be using the same port?

For some reason I have IIS 6 and IIS 7 on the same machine.  I seem to be unable to start IIS 7 but it seems I can in IIS 6.  Yet, I am able to see c:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm but I am not able to see a viable http://localhost

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop one of them, or set the other to listen to a different port.

[How to set the port for IIS Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605)

Answer (score 1):

Pekka has one solution but another solution to this problem which I think is more common is to use HTTP host headers. Host headers allow multiple sites to be hosted on one port (commonly 80 for http) using one public IP address. If you are interested in how they work you should check out google for HTTP header design and IIS host headers. I've provided a link to get you started how ever for the short term.

Here is a link that shows how to set them up in IIS 6.

http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/

And another

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190008

Cheers,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your setup is borked. On the other hand, Skype, among other programs grabs port 80 by default (or it certainly used to).

Try `netstat -abn` for more info about what is using the port.

Answer (score 0):

trying netsat-abn produced a lot of output.  What exactly am I looking for and what am I supposed to do once I find it?

Comment: Look for "80" in the netstat output. Best is to pipe netstat to a text file, then search the text file.

You are looking for the app that has 80 hooked.

Comment: OK, I think I know what process to stop now based on the process ID I got.  

I thought that the task manager showed a list of running processes, but when I bring up the task manager I do not see any process ID's.  How do I find the right process to stop?

Here is a snapshot of the task manager:
http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/taskmgr.gif
here is a closer view:
http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/taskmgr-1.gif